# Signature cryptographic validation not successful opensaml

Tags: java, validation, saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

I am trying to do signature validation on SAML2 Response which is obtained from an identity provider using OpenSAML. I am trying to read the response from the localfile system.

Here is my code:

```
  DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();
  BasicParserPool ppMgr = new BasicParserPool();
  ppMgr.setNamespaceAware(true);

 //Read file from the filesystem

 File file1=new File("F:/Softwares/Assertion.xml");
 InputStream inCommonSaml=new FileInputStream(file1);

 // Parse file
Document inCommonSamlDoc = ppMgr.parse(inCommonSaml);
Element metadataRoot = inCommonSamlDoc.getDocumentElement();
UnmarshallerFactory    unmarshallerFactory=configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory();
 Unmarshaller unmarshaller =    unmarshallerFactory.getUnmarshaller(metadataRoot);
 Response  inCommonSamlRes = (Response)  unmarshaller.unmarshall(metadataRoot);

  //Get certificate
   SignatureValidator signatureValidator = new SignatureValidator(cert);
   Signature  signature=inCommonSamlRes.getSignature();
   signatureValidator.validate(signature);


   try {
        BasicX509Credential credential = new BasicX509Credential();

        File file2=new File("F:/Softwares/publicKey.crt");
        InputStream samlCertificate=new FileInputStream(file2);         
          CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        //    
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate certificate = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(samlCertificate);
           // 

            X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec((certificate).getPublicKey().getEncoded());
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PublicKey key = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);


            credential.setPublicKey(key);
            Object obj = (credential).getPublicKey();
            if (obj instanceof RSAPublicKey) {
                BigInteger modulus = ((RSAPublicKey) obj).getModulus();
                BigInteger exponent = ((RSAPublicKey) obj).getPublicExponent();
                System.out.println("modulus");
                System.out.println (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(modulus.toByteArray()));
                System.out.println("public exponent:");
                System.out.println (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(exponent.toByteArray()));

    }
     //     System.out.println ("public key is: //n//r"+ credential.getPublicKey());
            return credential;  



    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e; //Throws a 'Signature did not validate against the credential's key' exception
    }
```

Note: I use the same certificate(publicKey.crt) to sign the assertion also.
I am getting the following error:
signature cryptographic validation not successful.

Please let me know where am I wrong? What does the error mean? Does it say that public and private keys are the same?

Thanks,
aswini J

Comment: Can you post assertion.xml on gist?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get .jks file from IdP (Identity Provider) server. Also when you're getting SAMLResponse from for your POST from IDP, this SAMLResponse should be containing Signature (FYI -  will be an encoded string, you can decode and read  using Open SAML library, available on Maven Central Repository).
Once you get signature from , you can validate that using OpenSAML

```
sigValidator.validate(response.getSignature());
```

This method will give you meesage if everything is OK. The message for reference **"Signature validated with key from supplied credentia"**

You can follow this link: http://sureshatt.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-read-saml-20-response-with.html to get Signature and

**(IMP)**: Your IDP (Identity Provider) should be send  (may be via HTTP POST), so that you can get  from  which can have NameID i.e, ClinetId

Comment: .jks? Do you mean java keys? How to get it? I am using a java based tool as an identity provider.Thanks

Comment: No, its created by keytool. Which IDP(Identity Provider) you're using ? In my App, I'm using WSO2 IDP which has wso2carbon.jks file. This file contains public and private keys...PrivateKey is with me and public keys with server, they're keypair to identify each others identity,

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for incoming people getting this error and searching on Google.

In my case, I am facing the same error :"**error: signature cryptographic validation not successful**", with a slightly different case. I am validating with *SimpleSamlPHP* as **SP** and *CAS* as **IDP**.

The problem was that my **SP** uses one (self-signed) cert for SP validation to IDP, and another cert for SP in Apache to make allow SSL (so that I can have https)

Using two separate cert might works fine for a lot of process like login and metadata validation, but with prcess like logout the above error will happen.

The solution is to use only one cert for both process, and my error is gone.